# How can I catch all exceptions, when I want to show a report and Crystal reports is not installed?

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports

I have a tool, which reads data from a database, modifies it and then displays it in a crystal reports report, which is shown in a separate window.

The tool is sometimes used by people, who do not have Crystal Reports installed, so I want to display specific error message, which tells the user exactly what to do (instead of the generic message right now).

I'm calling the window with the report like this:

```
try
{
    ReportWindow report = new ReportWindow(resultList);
    report.Show();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    this.LogAction("Could not open the report. To view it, you need to have Crystal Reports installed.", Notification.Error);
}
```

(the catch branch is simplified for the sake of this question)

ReportWindow.xaml.cs

```
public ReportWindow(List<MeasureTestResult> measurement)
{
    this._measurementList = measurement;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

ReportWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ResultFileViewer.Sources.ReportWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:viewer="clr-namespace:SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer;assembly=SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer">
    <viewer:CrystalReportsViewer Name="CrystalReportsViewer1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />    
</Window>
```

The line `InitializeComponent();` in the `ReportWindow` constructor throws several exceptions, like `XamlParseException` or an `InvalidCastException`. The problem is, that only the `XamlParseException` is caught by the catch. The other exceptions are only handled by my `DispatcherUnhandledException` property of my App.xaml.

This is problematic because it either means that the whole application is shut down when e.Handled is set to false or a zombie process remains after the application is closed by the user, when e.Handled is set to true.

How can I catch the currently unhandled exception in the class, that is calling the report window?

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823929/can-i-handle-thrown-exceptions-in-xaml), but that also didn't catch the `InvalidCastException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've abandoned trying to catch the rogue exception, as I was not successfull doing it. 
Instead I tried to detect beforehand, if Crystal Reports is installed. I basically found two alternatives:

- Check the registry for specific entries
- Check the global assembly cache (GAC), if the needed assemblies are there

The registry check has the disadvantage, that it only does contain a rather generic name instead of a specific version entry (like for example `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0`).
Additionally, if you have had Crystal Reports installed beforehand and uninstalled it, for whatever reason, the registry entry would persist and therefore also be no realiable check to see if Crystal Reports is installed.

So I went with the GAC check, which I did this way:

```
try
{
    // 13.0.2000.0 is Crystal Reports for VS 2010
    // the first assembly is the most important one, but it also gets deployed by the project itself
    // because of this I picked two additional assemblies to check for
    var a = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304");
    result = a != null;
    a = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.TemplateEngine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304");
    result &= a != null;
    a = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304");
    result &= a != null;
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
{
    this.LogAction("Could not open the report. To view it, you need to have Crystal Reports v13.0.12 (32-bit only) installed.");
    result = false;
}
catch
{
    //Runtime is in GAC but something else prevents it from loading. (bad install?, etc)
    result = false;
}
```

Which works as expected.